# What is the relation between a learning rate scheduler and an optimizer?

Tags: python, pytorch

If I have a model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class net_x(nn.Module): 
        def __init__(self):
            super(net_x, self).__init__()
            self.fc1=nn.Linear(2, 20) 
            self.fc2=nn.Linear(20, 20)
            self.out=nn.Linear(20, 4) 

        def forward(self, x):
            x=self.fc1(x)
            x=self.fc2(x)
            x=self.out(x)
            return x

nx = net_x()
```

And then I'm defining my inputs, optimizer (with `lr=0.1`), scheduler (with `base_lr=1e-3`), and training:

```
r = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0])
optimizer = optim.Adam(nx.parameters(), lr = 0.1)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR(optimizer, base_lr=1e-3, max_lr=0.1, step_size_up=1, mode="triangular2", cycle_momentum=False)

path = 'opt.pt'
for epoch in range(10):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    net_predictions = nx(r)
    loss = torch.sum(torch.randint(0,10,(4,)) - net_predictions)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    print('loss:' , loss)
    
    #save state dict
    torch.save({    'epoch': epoch,
                    'net_x_state_dict': nx.state_dict(),
                    'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
                    'scheduler': scheduler.state_dict(),    
                    }, path)
#loading state dict
checkpoint = torch.load(path)        
nx.load_state_dict(checkpoint['net_x_state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
scheduler.load_state_dict(checkpoint['scheduler'])
```

The optimizer seems to take the learning rate of the scheduler

```
for g in optimizer.param_groups:
    print(g)
>>>
{'lr': 0.001, 'betas': (0.9, 0.999), 'eps': 1e-08, 'weight_decay': 0, 'amsgrad': False, 'initial_lr': 0.001, 'params': [Parameter containing:
```

Does the learning rate scheduler overwrite the optimizer? How does it connect to it? Trying to understand the relation between them (i.e how they interact, etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The LR scheduler contains the optimizer as a member and alters its parameters learning rates explicitly.

---

As mentioned in [PyTorch Official Documentations](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html), the learning rate scheduler receives the optimizer as a parameter in its constructor, and thus has access to its parameters.

The common use is to update the LR after every epoch:

```
scheduler = ... # initialize some LR scheduler
for epoch in range(100):
    train(...) # here optimizer.step() is called numerous times.
    validate(...)
    scheduler.step()
```

All optimizers inherit from a common parent class `torch.nn.Optimizer` and are updated using the `step` method implemented for each of them.

Similarly, all LR schedulers (besides `ReduceLROnPlateau`) inherit from a common parent class named `_LRScheduler`. Observing its [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html#LambdaLR) uncovers that in the `step` method the class indeed changes the LR of the parameters of the optimizer:

```
...
for i, data in enumerate(zip(self.optimizer.param_groups, values)):
            param_group, lr = data
            param_group['lr'] = lr
...
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot. So if I wanted to change the learning rate of the scheduler like I would with the optimizer: `optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] = 0.0001` is there a similar way to do so? Since it's going to override the optimizer

Comment: If you want to override the learning rate of the LR scheduler you can override its `_last_lr` member, and the next time you take a step with the scheduler it will update according to this new LR. However, this isn't such a good practice since you override a private member. Consider using `MultiStepLR` that enables you to manually choose the LR at each scheduler's step.

Comment: Got it. So a simple `scheduler._last_lr = 0.0001` after `scheduler.load_state_dict` ?

Comment: yes, but once again, consider using a different lr scheduling policy

Comment: Yea makes sense. I'm mostly doing it to test the optimal lowest learning rate. Already have a trained model that needs to have its lr lowered and the `CyclicLR` works well. I really appreciate the help : )